# Difference of Flavor between Pure Math and Mathematical Computer Science

Tags: computer-science, career-development

I'm entering a PhD program with two options -- pure math and mathematical computer science (MCS) -- and I'm torn between the decision. As an undergrad, I loved pure math and that's why I applied to grad school. I have no doubt that I could stay awake at night thinking about differential geometry for the next few years and really enjoy it. My experience with MCS is limited to a couple chapters of an algorithms book and a few weeks of Stanford's machine learning MOOC. What I've seen has been interesting and beautiful, but I'm not as confident I would love it. As choosing a track requires planning courses semesters in advance, I cannot easily switch after choosing, so I want to make the best decision from my current point.

So, my question is: **How can I tell whether or not I would enjoy mathematical computer science?** How does it compare in flavor, style, to areas like analysis, algebra, etc? How might doing a PhD in either area differ as a student, and how might it affect future job prospects? Is it a good idea at all to make a switch without in depth prior knowledge?

I am not looking for answers that advise me to question why I am or if I should be in a PhD program since I'm undecided, nor am I looking for answers that are basically 'don't worry about it, just find something you enjoy.'

I realize this might not be the right forum to post this in, but I didn't think it fit the academia stack exchange. Please let me know if there's a more appropriate place to post this.

Comment: Better job prospects in theoretical computer science. E.g., you might have opportunities with groups like Microsoft Research. This question isn't exactly suitable for this site, so I will have to vote to close, unfortunately.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Is there somewhere more appropriate I can ask this question?

Comment: I think I understand what you are struggling with, since I am making a similiar transition to more applied mathematics at the moment. What kind of subjects will you be studying in Mathematical Computer Science? It is a wide field after all

Comment: Thanks for relating MF14. I think I would be most interested in Algorithms around AI, but I'm not sure/specific probably _because_ I don't have much experience in the field. I can say things like cryptography and logic aren't overwhelmingly interesting to me, so I doubt I would go there though..